# A question about applying np.unique or npi.unique to partial arrays

Tags: arrays, numpy, numpy-indexed

Consider `arr` having `shape (5, 6)` where every row is unique:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy_indexed as npi
from itertools import permutations

arr = np.array([[1, 3, 5, 7, 3, 1],
                [5, 5, 1, 1, 1, 9],
                [2, 4, 6, 8, 4, 2],
                [5, 5, 1, 1, 1, 4],
                [8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 0]])
```

First, I find all full-row permutations of `arr`.  As expected, the resulting `arr_p` has `shape (120, 5, 6)`.

```
arr_p = np.array([arr[i, :] for i in permutations(range(len(arr)))])
```

Next, I find the unique 2d arrays in `arr_p` **CONSIDERING ONLY the first 5 columns of `arr_p`**. As expected, the resulting `arr_up` has `shape (60, 5, 6)` because, in this example, the 2nd and 4th rows are identical in the first 5 columns:

```
arr_up, idx = npi.unique(arr_p[:, :, :-1], return_index = True, axis=0)
```

Finally, I put the surviving permutations in their original order:

```
out = arr_p[idx]
```

**QUESTION**  as it applies to array `arr`:  
Because  row `[5, 5, 1, 1, 1, 9]`  appears **ABOVE** row `[5, 5, 1, 1, 1, 4]` in `arr`,  will it **ALWAYS appear ABOVE** row `[5, 5, 1, 1, 1, 4]` in EVERY unique 2d array found in `out`?
This is, if fact, true in this small example, but is it guaranteed to be true?